# Unable to find vcvarshall.bar in Python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, blender

How can I get rid of this error:-

> unable to find vcvarshall.bat

I am trying to compile animation nodes 2.0 addon for blender **32 bit**, I can't find 32 bit version of the addon, it doesn't have wheel, I have installed anaconda, created Python 3.5 environment, Visual Studio Community 2017, visual c++ 2015 and 2017 and updated setup tools yet I still get "unable to find vcvarshall.bat"

Python 3.6 compiles the addon, but blender isn't able to accept it!

Please advise how to avoid the above error in Python 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

I installed visual c++ build tools from here: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691126

and then i ran animation nodes 2.0 addon using x86 native command prompt which can be found in start -> all programs -> visual studio 2017 -> VC.

When i run it through default command prompt, it shows error!